# Side Navigation bar jumps to top after selecting specific page from Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

I am having an issue with Navigation Bar jumping to the top after selecting specific page. I want to side bar to stay same position after selecting the page. I found few similar questions here but the given solutions didn't solve my issue. Here the Code.

**SideBarItem.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
import { AiOutlineLeft, AiOutlineDown } from 'react-icons/ai';

const SidebarHeader = ({ toggleSideBar, transKey }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <li
      name={transKey}
      id={transKey}
      className={classnames('nav-small-cap', { 'dots-icon': !toggleSideBar })}>
      {!toggleSideBar && <i className="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i>}
      {toggleSideBar && <span className="hide-menu">{t(transKey)}</span>}
    </li>
  );
};

const SidebarItem = ({
  route,
  icon,
  toggleSideBar,
  transKey,
  isHeader,
  subs,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const selectedClassName = router.pathname === route ? 'selected' : null;

  return (
    <>
      {isHeader && (
        <SidebarHeader
          toggleSideBar={toggleSideBar}
          transKey={transKey}
          id={transKey}
        />
      )}

      {!isHeader && (
        <li className={classnames('sidebar-item', selectedClassName)}>
          <div className="sidebar-link clickable text-white-100 waves-effect waves-dark">
            <i className={icon} style={{ color: 'white' }}></i>
            {toggleSideBar && (
              <div className="arrow-style">
                {!subs && (
                  <Link href={route}>
                    <a className="hide-menu">&nbsp;{t(transKey)}</a>
                  </Link>
                )}
                {subs && (
                  <>
                    <a className="hide-menu" onClick={handleToggle}>
                      &nbsp;{t(transKey)}
                    </a>
                    <div className="sidebar-arrow">
                      {isOpen ? <AiOutlineDown /> : <AiOutlineLeft />}
                    </div>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>

          {subs && (
            <ul
              className={classnames('collapse', 'first-level', {
                show: isOpen,
              })}>
              {subs.map((subNavItem) => (
                <SidebarItem
                  key={subNavItem.transKey}
                  {...subNavItem}
                  toggleSideBar={toggleSideBar}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </li>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SidebarItem;
```

**SidebarLinks.js** file

```
import React from 'react';
import navItems from '@constants/navItems';
import SidebarItem from './SidebarItem';

const SidebarLinks = (props) => {
  return (
    <nav className="sidebar-nav">
      <ul id="sidebarnav" className="in">
        {navItems.map((navItem) => (
          <SidebarItem key={navItem.transKey} {...navItem} {...props} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default SidebarLinks;
```

**LayoutWithSidebar.js** file

```
import React from 'react';
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
import SidebarFooter from '@components/Sidebar/SidebarFooter';
import UserProfile from '@components/Sidebar/UserProfile';
import SidebarLinks from '@components/Sidebar/SidebarLinks';
import Styles from './styles';

const LayoutWithSidebar = ({ toggleSideBar, setToggleSidebar, btn }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const handleEnterMouse = () => {
    setToggleSidebar(true);
  };
  return (
    <aside
      className={`left-sidebar-style ${
        toggleSideBar ? 'open-left-sidebar' : 'left-sidebar'
      }`}
      onMouseEnter={handleEnterMouse}
      data-sidebarbg="skin5">
      <div className="scroll-sidebar">
        <UserProfile btn={btn} toggleSideBar={toggleSideBar} translation={t} />
        <SidebarLinks btn={btn} toggleSideBar={toggleSideBar} translation={t} />
      </div>
      {(toggleSideBar || btn) && <SidebarFooter />}
      <style jsx toggleSideBar={toggleSideBar}>
        {Styles}
      </style>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default LayoutWithSidebar;
```

App.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
import AccountOverview from '@components/Dashboard/AccountOverview';
import Exposure from '@components/Dashboard/Exposure';
import PerformanceStats from '@components/Dashboard/PerformanceStats';
import CommissionAndBalance from '@components/Dashboard/CommissionAndBalance';
import MostRecentConversions from '@components/Dashboard/MostRecentConversions/index';
import Announcement from '@components/Dashboard/Announcement';
import TopPublishers from '@components/Dashboard/TopPublishers';
import ClickByCountries from '@components/Dashboard/TotalVisits/index';
import ClickPerDevice from '@components/Dashboard/OurVisitors/index';
import useShallowEqualSelector from '@hooks/useShallowEqualSelector';
import BaseLayout from '@layouts/BaseLayout';
import { formatNumber } from '@utils';
import routes from '@constants/routes';

import {
  fetchAccountOverviewDataAction,
  fetchPerformanceStatAction,
  fetchAnnouncementAction,
  fetchCommissionBalanceAction,
  fetchExposuresAction,
  fetchRecentConversionAction,
  fetchTopPublishersAction,
  fetchVisitorDataAction,
} from '@actions';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [announcementRole, setAnnouncementRole] = useState('advertiser');
  const [statFilter, setStatFilter] = useState('day');

  const {
    accountOverview,
    exposures,
    visitors,
    commissionBalance,
    recentConversions,
    topPublishers,
    performanceStatistics,
  } = useShallowEqualSelector(({ stat }) => {
    return stat;
  });

  const {
    fetch: { list: announcements, status: announcementFetchStatus },
  } = useShallowEqualSelector((state) => state.announcements);

  const {
    get: { currencyCode },
  } = useShallowEqualSelector((state) => state.stat?.recentConversions);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCommissionBalanceAction());
    dispatch(fetchRecentConversionAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAccountOverviewDataAction());
    dispatch(fetchExposuresAction());
    dispatch(fetchTopPublishersAction());
    dispatch(fetchVisitorDataAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPerformanceStatAction({ filter: statFilter }));
  }, [dispatch, statFilter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      fetchAnnouncementAction({ role: announcementRole, page: 1, perPage: 4 })
    );
  }, [dispatch, announcementRole]);

  return (
    <BaseLayout
      metaPageTitle={t('dashboard:pageTitle')}
      pageTitle={t('dashboard:pageTitle')}
      pageSubtitle={t('dashboard:pageSubtitle')}
      breadcrumbPaths={[
        { url: routes.dashboard.url, text: t('common:home') },
        { text: t('dashboard:pageTitle') },
      ]}>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <AccountOverview
                accountOverview={accountOverview.get.data}
                isLoading={accountOverview.get.status === 'loading'}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }
        {
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <PerformanceStats
                isLoading={performanceStatistics.get.status === 'loading'}
                setStatFilter={setStatFilter}
                statFilter={statFilter}
                performanceStatistics={performanceStatistics.get.data}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }

        {
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <Exposure
                exposures={exposures.get.data}
                isLoading={exposures.get.status === 'loading'}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }

        {
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <CommissionAndBalance
                commissionBalance={commissionBalance.get.data}
                isLoading={commissionBalance.get.status === 'loading'}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12}>
            <MostRecentConversions
              isLoading={recentConversions.get.status === 'loading'}
              recentConversions={recentConversions.get.data}
              t={t}
              currencyCode={currencyCode}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <Col sm={12}>
            <div className="card-deck mb-4">
              {
                <Announcement
                  announcements={announcements}
                  announcementRole={announcementRole}
                  isLoading={announcementFetchStatus === 'loading'}
                  setAnnouncementRole={setAnnouncementRole}
                  t={t}
                />
              }
              <TopPublishers
                isLoading={topPublishers.get.status === 'loading'}
                topPublishers={topPublishers.get.data}
                t={t}
                formatNumber={formatNumber}
                format
              />
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        {
          <Row>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <ClickByCountries
                isLoading={visitors.get.status === 'loading'}
                totalVisitors={visitors.get.data?.totalVisitors}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6}>
              <ClickPerDevice
                isLoading={visitors.get.status === 'loading'}
                ourVisitors={visitors.get.data?.ourVisitors}
                t={t}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }
      </div>
    </BaseLayout>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

It would be great if you can assist.
P.S. I already looked through some answers here but it didn't work for me.

PLS check video link below

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/4xzlBfhQcKQ

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem, maybe with a GIF?

Comment: Here is the link for the video https://www.youtube.com/shorts/4xzlBfhQcKQ @404answernotfound

Comment: @kalibri_code_2022 I think I can solve it but need to check your app.js first? can you provide screenshot on it?

Comment: @kalibri_code_2022 that's happening because you probably wrapped your sidebar inside the entire page component which rerenders on every page change. If you want to stop that behavior, just unwrap the component and take out the sidebar

Comment: @Rayl i just added App.js file. pls check thanks

Comment: @kalibri_code_2022 Thanks, put your sidebar component in your app.js. don't wrap it with your layout component. There would be a little adjustment in your css thou maybe width of the sidebar and the main content or make the sidebar fixed and so on.. but the main concept is try to separate the main layout and sidebar. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Rayl Thank you for your response. I tried what you said, but no success. Any other suggestions? FYI I m using NEXT.js and I used <Link href="/some-page" scroll={false}>  -> scroll={false}, this didn't help as well.

Comment: I see, hmm. links doesn't do with this problem I think. Is that sidebar is inside the layout. Ahm, so you're using Next, so in your index.js Put your sidebar component there. below is your main layout. make sure your main layout has margin or padding left that has exact width for the sidebar. then make your sidebar fixed.

Comment: @Rayl I tried that way as well, but still no success. Side bar keeps jumping to top

Answer (score 0):

From the video that you showed and the code you shared it seems that you wrapped your sidebar along with the entire application and pages components. If you want to avoid "rerendering" the sidebar, which is the thing that applies the "go to the top" effect, you should unwrap the layout with sidebar from the route changing, this will prevent this behaviour.